# My code radio button doesn't work when I run it

Tags: java, android-studio

When i'm running my project there
was no error message
but when I chose one answer
there was no correct answer
from the three options,
the same thing happened to
the other questions.
I don't know where the problem lies.
please tell me where the error is.
thank you

I'm still a beginner in Android Studio.
so I don't really understand

QuizActivity.java

```
public class quizmateri1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private TextView questionTV;
    private RadioGroup optionRadioGroup;
    private Button submitButton;
    private ImageButton playButton;
    private int currentQuestionIndex = 0; // index untuk pertanyaan saat ini
    private Question[] questions;
    private int score = 0;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quizmateri1);

    questionTV = findViewById(R.id.soal);
    playButton = findViewById(R.id.soalsound);
    optionRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.optionRadioGroup);
    submitButton = findViewById(R.id.next);

    //pertanyaan
    questions = new Question[]{
            new Question("namo", new String[]{"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}, "Correct Answer 1"),
            new Question("ake", new String[]{"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}, "Correct Answer 2"),
         //boleh tambah pertanyaan
    };

    //load pertanyaan pertama
    loadQuestion(currentQuestionIndex);

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playAudio(questions[currentQuestionIndex].getAudioFileName());
        }
    });

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           checkAnswer();
        }
    });
}

    private void loadQuestion(int questionIndex) {

        // set text pertanyaan
        questionTV.setText("Soal " + (questionIndex + 1));

        // reset pilihan jawaban
        optionRadioGroup.clearCheck();

        // set pilihan jawaban
        RadioButton option1 = findViewById(R.id.option1);
        RadioButton option2 = findViewById(R.id.option2);
        RadioButton option3 = findViewById(R.id.option3);

        option1.setText(questions[questionIndex].getOptions()[0]);
        option2.setText(questions[questionIndex].getOptions()[1]);
        option3.setText(questions[questionIndex].getOptions()[2]);
    }

    private void playAudio(String audioFileName) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(audioFileName, "raw", getPackageName());
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void checkAnswer() {
       // jawaban user
        int selectedId = optionRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton selectedRadioButton = findViewById(selectedId);
  ///      RadioButton selectedRadioButton = findViewById(optionRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
  ///      int selectedId = optionRadioGroup.indexOfChild(selectedRadioButton);

        if (selectedRadioButton != null) {
            String selectedAnswer = selectedRadioButton.getText().toString();
            String correctAnswer = questions[currentQuestionIndex].getCorrectAnswer();

            if (selectedAnswer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
                score++;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "InCorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            currentQuestionIndex++; // pindah soal berikut

            if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.length) {
                loadQuestion(currentQuestionIndex);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Quiz selesai! Skore Anda: " + score, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Silahkan pilih jawaban!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Question.java

```
public class Question {
    private String audioFileName;
    private String[] options;
    private String correctAnswer;

    public Question(String audioFileName, String[] options, String correctAnswer) {
        this.audioFileName = audioFileName;
        this.options = options;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

    public String getAudioFileName() {
        return audioFileName;
    }

    public String[] getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }
}
```

activity_quiz.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D3FBB6"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Scroe : 0"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardv"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scoreTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/soal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Pertanyaan"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/soalsound"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/soal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_volume"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/optionRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="381dp"
            android:layout_height="272dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardv"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:elevation="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/optiondesain"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Option 1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/optiondesain"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Option 2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/option3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/optiondesain"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Option 3" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/optionRadioGroup"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="SELANJUTNYA"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you debugged our app? do you have a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like a logic problem. Your answers are "Option 1", "Option 2" and "Option 3". Whatever you select, it's not going to be equal to "Correct answer 1", so as implemented now, it will always say "InCorrect!" and move to the next question, or finish. Change "Correct answer 1" to either "Option 1", "Option 2" or "Option 3", so one of them is equal to the correct answer:

```
questions = new Question[]{
        new Question("namo", new String[]{"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}, "Option 2"),
        new Question("ake", new String[]{"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}, "Option 3"),
};
```

So the correct answer for first question will be the second radio button "Option 2" and for the second question "Option 3" will be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the "checkAnswer" function, the 2 String you compare will never be the same. When you create a question, you make the correct answer `"Correct answer 1"` and the options as `"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"`. So when you check if the answer was correct, you always get false since `"Correct answer 1"` is not one of the option.

Instead of setting the correctAnswer as "correct answer 1" in the constructor, you could set it as the index of the correct answer. So when you call getCorrectAnswer you could `return options[correctAnswerIndex]`

Hopefully this helps solves your issue